# Geometry problem of finding the area of triangle BOF

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

In triangle $ABC$, let $D$ be a point on side $BC$ such that $BD$ is $1/3$ of $BC$. Let $E$ be a point on side $AC$ such that $AE$ is $1/3$ of $AC$. Let $O$ be the circumcenter of triangle $ABC$, and let $F$ be the intersection of $BD$ and $OE$. If the radius of the circumcircle of triangle $ABC$ is $R$. Prove that the area of the triangle $BOF$ is $$
R^2 \sin(2A) + \sin(2B) - \sin(2C)\ 
$$

My Attempt

To prove that the area of triangle $BOF$ is $R^2 \sin(2A) + \sin(2B) - \sin(2C)$, I first established a few relationships involving the given information and then applied trigonometric identities.

In triangle $ABC$,
$$ \frac{BD}{DC} = \frac{1}{3} \implies BD = \frac{BC}{3} 
$$
Similarly,
$$ AE = \frac{AC}{3} $$

Since $O$ is the circumcenter of triangle $ABC$, we know that $O$ lies on the perpendicular bisectors of all three sides of the triangle. Hence, $BO = CO = R$.

Since $O$ is the circumcenter, $BO = 2R\sin A$, and similarly, $CO = 2R\sin B$. Also, $OE$ is the altitude from $O$ to $AC$, so $OE = R\cos C$.

Now, to find the area of triangle $BOF$, I first find the length of $BF$ and then used the formula for the area of a triangle.

$$ 
\begin{aligned}
BF &= BO + OF \\
 &= R + OE \\
 &= R + R\cos C \\
 &= R(1 + \cos C) \ .
\end{aligned}
$$

Now, using the Law of Cosines in triangle $BOC$,
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
BC^2 &= BO^2 + CO^2 - 2(BO)(CO)\cos C \\
&= (2R\sin A)^2 + (2R\sin B)^2 - 2(2R\sin A)(2R\sin B)\cos C \\
&= 4R^2(\sin^2A + \sin^2B - 2\sin A\sin B\cos C) \\
&= 4R^2(\sin^2A + \sin^2B - 2\sin A\sin B\cos C) \\
&= 4R^2(\sin^2A + \sin^2B - \sin^2C) \\
&= 4R^2(\sin^2A + \sin^2B - (1 - \cos^2C)) \\
&= 4R^2(\sin^2A + \sin^2B - 1 + \cos^2C) \\
&= 4R^2(\sin^2A + \sin^2B + \cos^2C - 1) \ .
\end{aligned}
$$

I don't know how to continue with the solution can anyone please help complete the proof.

Comment: Something is wrong with the text of your problem. Why did we even introduce the point D? It doesn’t participate in further construction. The fact that you use BD instead of BC further tells that something got mixed. Possibly D and E belong to other sides of ABC.

Comment: Please take a look if my edits are what you want... more on using mathjax to format mathematical pieces of text are here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Things are hard to understand. Why do we have $OE=OF$? Why is $OE$ the altitude from $O$ to $AC$? Is $E$ the mid point of $AC$ (against the stated construction of $E$) - are there more points $E$ in collision here?! A picture would be welcome...

Comment: Let's address each point step by step:

1. **Why do we have OE=OF?**
   Since O is the circumcenter of triangle ABC, OE and OF are both radii of the circumcircle. In any triangle, the perpendicular bisector of a side passes through the circumcenter, so OE and OF are both perpendicular bisectors of sides AC and BD, respectively. Hence, OE = OF.

2. **Why is OE the altitude from O to AC?**
   OE is not necessarily the altitude from O to AC. It's the perpendicular bisector of AC, which intersects AC at a right angle, but it may or may not pass through point E.

Comment: **Is E the midpoint of AC?**
   No, E is not necessarily the midpoint of AC. In the given construction, E is a point on AC such that AE is 1/3 of AC, which doesn't imply E is the midpoint.

Comment: Regarding the point E in collision maybe this will get clear only after drawing the diagram